# DATE_DIFF Function Possibilities in Bigquery

Tags: oracle, date, google-bigquery, datediff

currently I'm stuck on finding how to grouping Datediff into historical period.
let's say there are 2 people with active date: with the assumption today Current_date is 2021-05-17

```
ID     Active_date   Current_date    Date_diff
10001  2021-05-14    2021-05-17      3
10002  2021-05-12    2021-05-17      5
10002  2021-05-04    2021-05-17      13
10001  2021-05-01    2021-05-17      16
```

what I want to display is historical of Current_date - Active_date = Datediff

```
ID     Active_date   Current_date    Date_diff
10001  2021-05-14    2021-05-17      3
10002  2021-05-12    2021-05-17      5
10002  2021-05-04    2021-05-17      13
10001  2021-05-01    2021-05-17      16
10001  2021-05-14    2021-05-16      2
10002  2021-05-12    2021-05-16      4
10002  2021-05-04    2021-05-16      12
10001  2021-05-01    2021-05-16      15
....... and so on, until Date_diff is zero
```

how can I achieve this on Bigquery/Oracle?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Oracle?  Or in BigQuery?  They're different databases which support different SQL dialects and which have different built-in functions.

Comment: How does that output look like in e.g. 5th step? Does it still have 4 rows (but for ID = 10001 it keeps DATE_DIFF = 0, or is it removed from the list, or ...? Also, is CURRENT_DATE a column in that table, or do you just "know" that current date is (whichever current date is "today")?

Comment: @Littlefoot it repeat until the min(active_date). And for current_date, I just using the example so if you read this by tomorrow you don't have the wrong idea

Comment: @JustinCave I'm using both Oracle and Bigquery

Comment: Are you trying to find a single query that works in both databases?  Or are you asking two separate questions (one for each database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [generate_date_array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array):

```
with mytable as (
  select 10001 as id, date '2021-05-14' as active_date union all
  select 10002, date '2021-05-12'
)
select *, date_diff(curren_date, active_date, day) as diff
from mytable, unnest(generate_date_array(active_date, current_date())) as curren_date
```